# BInding Dictionary to a grid

Tags: c#, sql-server, xaml, windows-phone-8, grid

I am working on the Windows phone 8 application for the 1st time, and I am not that familiar with the controls and terms so please pardon me.

I have a windows phone 8 app which need to display a list of books ie: display book-title and book-desc in a list format.

I have used Windows phone DataBoundApp template for the project. I am trying to bind the grid with the database values.

Here is my code:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            using(Context c=new Context(Context.ConnectionString))
            {
                c.LogDebug = true;

                char[] allchar = new char[4] { 'A', 'B','C','D' };

                List<DB.Books> keys = new List<DB.Books>();

                var exampleDictionary = new Dictionary<List<DB.Books>, string>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {

                    var book = from m in c.Books
                               where m.Book_author.StartsWith(allchar[i].ToString())
                                orderby Convert.ToChar(m.Book_author)
                              select m;


                    keys.AddRange(book.ToList());

                    exampleDictionary.Add(book.ToList(), allchar[i].ToString());

                }
                MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = exampleDictionary.ToList();

            }

        }
```

And Xaml source:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key[1].Book_author}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </Grid>
```

Here I am trying to list the books in Alphabetical order, so the design should be as follows:

```
A:
book1-title,book1-desc
book2-title,book2-desc
book3-title,book3-desc
B:
book1-title,book1-desc
book2-title,book2-desc
book3-title,book3-desc
...
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First : What is the "Items" property? you set two time your item source list.

Comment: Second you can acces to your dictionnary in binding with only use key and value so Book_image and t doesn't exist and can't work

Comment: @MatDev8 I have modified my ode now. Please take a look. Yes the value for image and t does not exist.

Comment: @MatDev8 can you please let me know what do you mean by items property.

Comment: For create alpha group => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx. You set item source here ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" and MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = exampleDictionary.ToList();

Comment: OKay, got it. But even after I removed ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" from Xaml file, the code does not work for me.

Comment: Just a moment, the problem is just for group items? If it's that, my link will help you :) if you got an other error, say me what :)

Comment: @MatDev8 thanks a lot. your link solved my question.